# How to use `as` for wrapped react component by `styled()`

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

I want to change the tag type of the react component using `as` property. It looks does not work, contents will be disappeared.

I want to display `foo` text in the code below.
However, just exist `<p>` tag without value.

```js
const ChildComponent = () => <div>foo</div>;
const StyledChildComponent = styled(ChildComponent)`
  // some styles
`;

const ParentComponent = () => (
  <StyledChildComponent as="p" />
);
```

There is no error message on Chrome Dev Tool.

The versions of related modules are below

```
"react": "^16.8.6",
"react-dom": "^16.8.6",
"styled-components": "^4.2.0",
```

Comment: If you want to display `foo` then it should be `<StyledChildComponent as="p">foo</StyledChildComponent>`

Comment: It's just a sample. Actually `ChildComponent` is more complicated and I want to keep it as the other component. Do you know is it possible to do it?

Comment: Since you're wrapping `ChildComponent`, you should pass `forwardedAs`. Read here https://www.styled-components.com/docs/api#forwardedas-prop